# How to get older jquery versions to access SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm stuck using jquery 1.11.3 on an application, but jquery 1.11.3 doesn't seem to want to access elements in an SVG. Is this possible. I can't figure out why not.

Using **Jquery 1.11.3** - doesn't work (**update**, now uses version 1.12.4 and it works)

http://codepen.io/omarel/pen/zNMJOJ

Using **jquery 3.1** - works

http://codepen.io/omarel/pen/XpyBOq

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Rikin I realized I could use version 1.12.4 which starts adding classnames to SVG's and luckily this version works with the application I'm working on.

JQUERY

```
 $( ".amenitylink" ).on( "click", function() {
  $('svg #lobby').toggleClass("highlight");
 });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="amenitylink">click me</div>

 <svg version="1.1" id="main" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="276px" height="210px" viewBox="0 0 276 210" style="enable-background:new 0 0 276 210;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[
.st0{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:11;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
]]>
</style>
 <rect id="lobby" x="13" y="17" class="st0 " width="240" height="179"/>
 </svg>
```

CSS

```
 body {
 background-color:#000;
 color:#fff;
 }
.amenitylink {
cursor:pointer;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid white;
 }
 .highlight {
    fill:rgba(134, 117, 77, 0.4) !important;
}
```

Comment: It does target SVG element correctly but fails to add classname inside it. May be a known issue then and fixed at later version of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much. Even though there's no answer to this, your comment allowed me to go through the versions that did add the classname. I found 1.12.4 and it's still compatible with my application!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

As commented above v1.11.3 - It does target SVG element correctly but fails to add classname inside it. When I debugged it was showing something like this `[object SVGsomething] highlight`

SVG element class addition was resolved in ~1.12.4 library and you can use that to get your issue resolve.